# Universal Analytics and login redirect

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

As part of user flow on my site, user is redirected to a different domain that is not under my control, where he logs in and is then redirected back to my site.

Google analytics fail to correctly display the user flow, showing the callback URL as a new landing page, which is obviously wrong.

I am considering rewriting referrer on the callback page, but it seems like a very hacky solution to a common problem.

Is there a standard way to connect the flow after a redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enter the domain of that site in the **Referral exclusions** list in the Properties settings.